# Multivariable Taylor series proof

Tags: multivariable-calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

I was wondering if the proof I used for single variable taylor series[Proof of 1 variable Taylor series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GUtLtRDox3c) could be generalized for multivariable taylor series by considering the partial derivatives.

Comment: Why this downvote ?

Comment: What about considering $f(x,y)$ seen as a function of $x$ with $y$ a fixed parameter, and obtain its Taylor development, then make $y$ variable and expand all terms by Taylor ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust That is what I wanted to do but I don't know if that's mathemathically rigorous,I study engineering that's why I'm asking experts

Comment: There is no problem to make it rigorous: just apply the conditions of applicability of 1D Taylor every time you use it.

Comment: @YvesDaoust thank you :D